# How do you perform a command on all results of a search in Vim?

Tags: vim

Ideally, it'd be a variation of the following:

```
:/somesearchstring/ norm! dd
```

The above searches for a string and performs a normal mode command (in this case, deleting the line). The problem is, this only performs the command on the first occurrence of the search. How do you perform an **arbitrary command** on the results of a search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:g` like so:

```
:g/somesearchstring/norm! dd
```

or

```
:g/somesearchstring/d
```

See

```
:h :g
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
:g/somesearchstring/d
```

Explanation:

```
:g                  # Repeat for...
/somesearchstring/  # Each line which matches 'somesearchstring'
d                   # delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the g ("global") prefix:

:g/text_to_delete/d